High mean squared error in the kaggle house price prediction project
I'm a beginner in data science and working on the House Price Prediction problem. However, I'm facing a challenge with high mean squared error in my predictions. Could someone please assist me in identifying where I might be going wrong and how I can improve my model? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Link : https://www.kaggle.com/code/kohbala/housepricepredcition
Thanks!
Please go through the project.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

A high mean squared error may not be the wrong answer; it depends on the values being compared. mean squared error is almost as saying the square of the mean error, so it will be larger for large values.
using r2 and root_mean_squared_error also works well and will not scare you so much.
r2 values exist between 0 and 1 and rmse values may exist around your range of values

Thanks for replying Mr.Owen. I tried using sqrt of mean squared log error and the result is much better now.
